# Python Pulp absolute constraints

Tags: python, constraints, pulp

Suppose I have a set of decision variables in my PuLP definition:

```
vals = [-v for k, v in (DecisionVars.items())]
```

And I want to create a constraint related to the **absolute** value of the sum of all constraints. So something like:

```
for i in range(len(DecisionVars)):
   prob += lpSum(abs(vals[:i+1])) <= some_limit, "Absolute constraint"
```

But I cant seem to apply the `abs()` operator to my constraints?

**UPDATE**

Ok, if I make use of the information in this post [sum of absolute values constraint in semi definite programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795632/sum-of-absolute-values-constraint-in-semi-definite-programming) then my question can be formulated differently. I am now trying to evaluate:

```
abs(x1) + abs(x2) + abs(x3) <= some_limit
```

As pointed out in the link above, the answer might be to create a 1-norm of the vector x (where x is the vector of decision variables as above). I can see that `numpy` has `numpy.linalg.norm` but I cannot see how this can recursively create my set of constraints in PuLP. I'm struggling to create the correct syntax using `lpSum`.

Comment: I think this is answered nicely here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795632/sum-of-absolute-values-constraint-in-semi-definite-programming

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sum of absolute values constraint in semi definite programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795632/sum-of-absolute-values-constraint-in-semi-definite-programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right for each variable

`X1` make two new non negative variables `Y1` and `Z1 >=0`

then set a constraint

`X1 == Y1 - Z1`

Then your abs constraint becomes

`Y1 + Z1 +.... <= 10`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have another variable and two sets of constraints for each of your absolute variables.

```
m += xn <= tn
m += -xn <= tn
```

then the sum of tn is the sum of the absolute value of xn.