# Maximum of minimum of distances (absolute value in PuLP)

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp, absolute-value

I have the following problem.

I have a finite set L of points in a n-dimensional space, and I have a model.

I want to find the point `x`, in a specific search space, which maximizes the distance to the set of points `d(x, L)`.

The distance `d(x, L)` though is the minimum Manhattan distance from `x` to any of the points `σ` in `L`, i.e.:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>

$$d(x, L) = \min_{\sigma \in L} d(x, \sigma) = \min_{\sigma \in L} \sum_{i = 1}^n |x_i - \sigma_i|$$
```

Therefore, the final optimization problem will be:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>

$$\max_{x \in \text{SearchSpace}} \min_{\sigma \in L} \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - \sigma_i|$$
```

Now, I am trying to solve the problem using linear programming, with the PuLP library in python. Though, I am facing problems with the absolute value.

I've been trying in many ways so far, trying to follow what described here [sum of absolute values constraint in semi definite programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795632/sum-of-absolute-values-constraint-in-semi-definite-programming), but did not manage.
This is what I have so far:

```py
# Define the dimensionality of the problem
n = len(model) #dimension of the space 
m = len(L) #number of points in L

# Create the LP problem

prob = plp.LpProblem("Maximize minimal manhattan distance", plp.LpMaximize)

# Define the decision variables

x = plp.LpVariable.dicts("x", range(n), lowBound=0, cat = 'Continuous')

# Define the variable to maximize
z = plp.LpVariable("z", lowBound=0, cat = 'Continuous')

print(x, z)

# Define the constraints for x, i.e. the search space constraints
for i in range(n):
    if i == 0:
        prob += x[i] >= model[i][0]
        prob += x[i] <= model[i][1]
    else:
        prob += x[i] >= model[i][0] + x[i-1]
        prob += x[i] <= model[i][1] + x[i-1]

# Define the constraints for the absolute value of the difference between x and each point in L

# first way, still not working
for j in range(m): #for every sigma in L
    
    #prob += z <= plp.lpSum([abs(x[i] - L[j][i]) for i in range(n)])  
    diff = plp.LpVariable.dicts("diff_" + str(j), range(n), lowBound=0, cat = 'Continuous')
    #y = plp.LpVariable.dicts("y_var" + str(j), range(n), lowBound=0, cat = 'Continuous')
    #w = plp.LpVariable.dicts("w_var" + str(j), range(n), lowBound=0, cat = 'Continuous')
    diff_plus = plp.LpVariable.dicts("diff_plus" + str(j), range(n), lowBound=0, cat = 'Continuous')
    diff_minus = plp.LpVariable.dicts("diff_minus" + str(j), range(n), lowBound=0, cat = 'Continuous')
    
    for i in range(n):
        #print(x[i])
        prob += diff[i] == L[j][i] - x[i]

        prob += diff[i] == diff_plus[i] - diff_minus[i]
        prob += diff_plus[i] >= 0
        prob += diff_minus[i] >= 0
    
    prob += z <= plp.lpSum([diff_plus[i] + diff_minus[i] for i in range(n)])


print(prob)

# Define the objective function

prob += z

# Solve the problem

prob.solve()

# Print the results

print("Status:", plp.LpStatus[prob.status])
print("Objective value:", plp.value(prob.objective))


print("z:", plp.value(z))


optimal_point = [plp.value(x[i]) for i in range(n)]
print('Optimal Point:', optimal_point)
```

The problematic part is the following:

```py
# Define the constraints for the absolute value of the difference between x and each point in L
for j in range(m): #for every sigma in L
    
    #prob += z <= plp.lpSum([abs(x[i] - L[j][i]) for i in range(n)])  
    diff = plp.LpVariable.dicts("diff_" + str(j), range(n), lowBound=0, cat = 'Continuous')
    #y = plp.LpVariable.dicts("y_var" + str(j), range(n), lowBound=0, cat = 'Continuous')
    #w = plp.LpVariable.dicts("w_var" + str(j), range(n), lowBound=0, cat = 'Continuous')
    diff_plus = plp.LpVariable.dicts("diff_plus" + str(j), range(n), lowBound=0, cat = 'Continuous')
    diff_minus = plp.LpVariable.dicts("diff_minus" + str(j), range(n), lowBound=0, cat = 'Continuous')
    
    for i in range(n):
        #print(x[i])
        prob += diff[i] == L[j][i] - x[i]

        prob += diff[i] == diff_plus[i] - diff_minus[i]
        prob += diff_plus[i] >= 0
        prob += diff_minus[i] >= 0
    
    prob += z <= plp.lpSum([diff_plus[i] + diff_minus[i] for i in range(n)])
```

because I should first use the new variable z as it is a maximin problem, and then write the absolute values as constraints, which I am not being able to do apparently.

How should I solve it? THX!

Comment: `diff[i]` should not be positive but free.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Fair, I changed it but still it does not work correctly, i.e. the actual best solution is not found. Thx!

Comment: Because of non convexity you need to make sure that one of `diff_minus[i],diff_plus[i]` is zero.

Comment: I just tried to change the constraint diff_minus[i] >= 0 to diff_minus[i] == 0 and still it does not give me the optimal result

Comment: Yes, that makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an example of your input data to test your code, I can't guarantee this solution will work for your problem:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import pulp as plp


def find_unique_name(prob: plp.LpProblem, name: str) -> str:
    """Find a unique variable name for the problem.

    If a variable with the given name exists, append '_<number>' to it,
    where <number> starts from 1 and increases until a unique name is found.

    Parameters
    ----------
    prob : pulp.LpProblem
        The problem to check for existing variable names.
    name : str
        The base name to check for uniqueness.

    Returns
    -------
    str
        A unique variable name.
    """
    if name not in prob.variablesDict():
        return name

    counter = 1
    while f"{name}_{counter}" in prob.variablesDict():
        counter += 1
    return f"{name}_{counter}"


def add_abs(
    prob: plp.LpProblem,
    var: plp.LpVariable | plp.LpAffineExpression,
    big_m: float | int = 100_000,
    abs_var_name: str | None = None,
) -> pulp.LpVariable:
    """
    Create an LP variable with the absolute value of a variable or expression.

    This function introduces an auxiliary variable to the linear programming
    problem that represents the absolute value of a provided variable or
    expression. It also adds the necessary constraints to ensure this auxiliary
    variable correctly captures the absolute value.

    Parameters
    ----------
    prob : pulp.LpProblem
        The optimization problem to which the absolute value variable is added.
    var : pulp.LpVariable | pulp.LpAffineExpression
        The variable or expression whose absolute value is to be represented.
    big_m : float | int, default=100000
        A large constant required to create the auxiliary constraints needed to
        create the variable that equals the absolute value of :param:`var`.
        The value needs to be greater than any value that :param:`var` can have.
    abs_var_name : str | None, optional
        The name for the absolute value variable. If None, a name is generated
        automatically.

    Returns
    -------
    pulp.LpVariable
        The auxiliary variable representing the absolute value of the provided
        variable or expression.

    Examples
    --------
    The following example demonstrates how the :func:`add_abs` can be used,
    to find the absolute value for the `x` variable, that has a range of:
    :math:`-10 \\leq{} \\text{x} \\leq{} 0`:

    >>> prob = pulp.LpProblem("MyProblem", sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
    >>> x = pulp.LpVariable("x", lowBound=-10, upBound=0)
    >>> abs_x = add_abs(prob, x)
    >>> prob.setObjective(abs_x)

    >>> print(pulp.LpStatus[prob.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=False))])
    'Optimal'

    >>> print(f"Objective Value: {prob.objective.value():.0f}")
    'Objective Value: 10'

    >>> for name, lpvar in prob.variablesDict().items():
    ...     print(f"{name} = {lpvar.value():.0f}")
    abs(x) = 10
    x = -10
    binary_var(x) = 0
    """
    var_name = "UNKNOWN_NAME"
    if isinstance(var, plp.LpAffineExpression):
        var_name = var.getName()
        if var_name is None:
            var_name = var.__str__()
    elif isinstance(var, plp.LpVariable):
        var_name = var.name

    if abs_var_name is None:
        abs_var_name = f"abs({var_name})"

    # Create the absolute value variable
    abs_var_name = find_unique_name(prob, abs_var_name)
    abs_var = plp.LpVariable(abs_var_name, lowBound=0)

    # Binary variable to determine the sign of 'var'
    binary_var_name = find_unique_name(prob, f"binary_var({var_name})")
    binary_var = plp.LpVariable(binary_var_name, cat=plp.LpBinary)

    # Add constraints
    prob += abs_var >= var
    prob += abs_var >= -var
    prob += abs_var <= var + big_m * (1 - binary_var)
    prob += abs_var <= -var + big_m * binary_var

    return abs_var


# Example for a 2-dimensional problem
model = [(0, 10), (0, 10)]   # This defines a 2-dimensional search space with each dimension ranging from 0 to 10
L = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)] # This defines 3 points in the 2-dimensional space

# Define the dimensionality of the problem
n = len(model) # Dimension of the space 
m = len(L)     # Number of points in L

# Create the LP problem
prob = plp.LpProblem("Maximize minimal manhattan distance", plp.LpMaximize)

# Define the decision variables
x = plp.LpVariable.dicts("x", range(n), lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')

# Define the variable to maximize
z = plp.LpVariable("z", lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')

# Define the constraints for x, i.e. the search space constraints
for i in range(n):
    if i == 0:
        prob += x[i] >= model[i][0]
        prob += x[i] <= model[i][1]
    else:
        prob += x[i] >= model[i][0] + x[i-1]
        prob += x[i] <= model[i][1] + x[i-1]

# Define the constraints for the absolute value of the difference between x and each point in L
for j in range(m): # for every sigma in L...
    diff = plp.LpVariable.dicts(f"diff_{j}", range(n), lowBound=0, cat = 'Continuous')
    
    for i in range(n):
        absdiff = add_abs(prob, L[j][i] - x[i], abs_var_name=f"abs_diff({j},{i})")
        prob += diff[i] == absdiff
    prob += z <= plp.lpSum([diff[i] for i in range(n)])


# Define the objective function
prob.setObjective(z)

# Solve the problem
prob.solve()

# Print the results
print("Status:", plp.LpStatus[prob.status])
print("Objective value:", plp.value(prob.objective))
print("z:", plp.value(z))

optimal_point = [plp.value(x[i]) for i in range(n)]
print('Optimal Point:', optimal_point)

# Prints:
#
# Status: Optimal
# Objective value: 19.0
# z: 19.0
# Optimal Point: [10.0, 20.0]
```

Basically, I've created a function called `add_abs` that returns a variable representing the absolute value of some `pulp.LpVariable` or `pulp.LpAffineExpression`. Then I used this function to define the absolute difference of `L[j][i] - x[i]` from your original code.

I've then tested the code using the following "dummy" values for `model` and `L`:

- `model = [(0, 10), (0, 10)]`
- `L = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]`

Comment: It does indeed work, thx!